# A doubt regarding differentiation using the chain rule.

Tags: calculus

The book "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Andrew Pressley says the following on pg. 11

> Let $\phi:\overline{t}\to t$, and $\psi=\phi^{-1}$. We have $\phi(\psi(t))=t$. Differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ by using the chain rule, we get $$\frac{d\phi}{d\overline{t}}\frac{d\psi}{dt}=1$$

Using the chain rule, shouldn't we instead have $$\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}\frac{d\psi}{dt}=1$$

Thank  you

Answer (score 2):

This is actually just a matter of notation, which can be, I admit, a little confuzing at first.

The term $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ means that you take a function $\phi$ which is a function of $t$ and you differentiate it. It basically stands for $$\frac{d\phi}{dt}(t) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\phi(t+h) - \phi(t)}{h}.$$

When you have a function $\phi(\psi(t))$, it's derivative is the derivative of $\phi$ *at the point* $\psi(t)$ multiplied by the derivative of $\psi$ at the point $t$.

It would, therefore, be confuzing to say $\frac{d\phi}{d\psi}$ since, in a way, the function $\phi$ is still a function of $\bar t$, it is just that you plut $\psi(t)$ into the value of $\bar t$.

---

For example, take $\psi(t)=\ln(t)$ and $\phi(\bar t) = e^{\bar t}$. Now the equation is $$e^{\ln t} = t$$
and you have to find the differential of $e^{\ln t}$. The diferential $\phi'(\psi(t))\cdot \psi'(t)=e^{\ln t}\cdot \frac1t$. The first value, $e^{\ln t}$, is attained by entering the value $\bar t=\psi(t)=\ln t$ into the formula $\phi'(t)=e^{\bar t}$.

What you should see is this: to calculate $\phi'(\psi(t))$, you have to first calculate the differential of $\phi$, and to do this, you do not have to look at $\psi$ at all, you just need the function $\phi$. Only once you have $\phi'$ can you calculate $\phi'(\psi(t))$. This is why the differential of $\phi$ is written as $\frac{d\phi}{d\bar t}$, because it is not dependent on $\psi$ (until you plug $\psi$ in, of course).

Comment: I don't think that is accurate. Consider $h(x)=\sin(x^2)$. If $f(x)=x^2$, $h(x)$ is equivalent to $\sin(f(x))$. Now $\frac{dh(x)}{dx}=\frac{dh(x)}{df(x)}.\frac{df(x)}{dx}$. We know that $h(x)$ is a function of $x$. However, we can't just directly put $\frac{dh(x)}{dx}$

Comment: See my edit to my answer if it makes it any clearer. Anyway, the question you are asking is a matter of notation. I advise you to actually debate it with some of your classmates and in person, because it is much easier to explain "live".

Comment: Also, you have $h(x)=\sin(x^2)$ and $\frac{dh}{dx}(x) = 2x\cos(x^2)$, so yes, you can write $\frac{dh}{dx}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\phi(\overline{t}) = t$$

$$\psi = \phi^{-1}$$

Hence $$\psi(t) = \overline{t}$$ (equation 1)

Differentiate equation 1 wrt $\displaystyle t$:

$$\psi'(t) = \frac{d\overline{t}}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{dt}{d\overline{t}}} = \frac{1}{\phi'(\overline{t})}$$

Rearranging, you get

$$\frac{d\phi}{d\overline{t}}.\frac{d\psi}{dt}=1$$